# Permission denied when calling a function when using SECURITY DEFINER even after GRANT ALL to role has been run

Tags: postgresql

Running the SQL below I get a permissions issue.

> [42501] ERROR: permission denied for schema myschema Where: PL/pgSQL function >myschema.test_func() line 8 at SQL statement

What permission to I need to grant to allow the SECURITY DEFINER to select/execute functions. ALL PERMISSIONS doesn't seem to work.

Looking at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html I don't see anything else I can grant to make this work.

I'm using Postgresql 11. Obviously if I make myrole a super user it works fine. Even putting the grants at the end gives the same error.

---

Edit:

I've not explained very well. The issue is not creating the functions I get the issue when the following line is called:
`SELECT myschema.test_func_2('foo', 'bar') INTO l_table_result;`

The creating of the function works fine, only when I run `select myschema.test_func();` do I get the SQL error.

I can't see what other permissions myrole needs in order to call another function.

```
CREATE ROLE myrole WITH NOLOGIN;

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS myschema;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema TO myrole ;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA myschema TO myrole ;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA myschema TO myrole ;


CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION myschema.test_func()
RETURNS BOOLEAN
    SECURITY DEFINER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    l_table_result BOOLEAN;
BEGIN

    RAISE LOG 'Will Get This Far ... ';

    SELECT myschema.test_func_2('foo', 'bar') INTO l_table_result;

    RAISE LOG 'But Not This Far';

    RETURN TRUE;

END;
$$;

/* OWNERSHIP AND PERMISSIONS*/
ALTER FUNCTION myschema.test_func OWNER to myrole;



CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION myschema.test_func_2(
                                p_foo VARCHAR(10),
                                p_bar VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
    SECURITY DEFINER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN

    RETURN TRUE;

END;
$$;

/* OWNERSHIP AND PERMISSIONS*/
ALTER FUNCTION myschema.test_func_2(VARCHAR, VARCHAR) OWNER to myrole;




select myschema.test_func();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `CREATE` privilege on a schema, to create new objects in that schema.
Thus `GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA myschema to myrole;` grants `myrole` the right to create this function. The documentation of this `GRANT` is also at the page you linked.

Anyway, you just created this user in your script, I guess you are not connected to the database with this user in that moment, so you might add `SET ROLE myrole;` before the creation of the function. You can kill the `ALTER FUNCTION` afterwards, eventhough sometimes you may want to keep it, this your decision.

A last remark: If you are trying to use this combo of `SECURITY DEFINER` and `ALTER FUNCTION` to get a function that executes as the user that really issued the `CREATE FUNCTION` (what might be, if you intentionally did not do the `SET ROLE`), this will not work. As stated [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html), the permissions are checked against the user that owns the function, not the one that created it.

**EDIT**: Answer from the comment, that really solved the (edited) problem

Eventhough creation is possible (perhaps just the way you choose via `ALTER FUNCTION` and not via `CREATE FUNCTION` with user `myrole`) and you can call the function, inside the function you are acting as user `myrole` and the lookup for function `myschema.test_func_2` is executed by him, thus `myrole` needs at least the `USAGE` privilege on the schema.

Comment: Thanks the issue is not creating the function the issue is when the function runs (even via  super user account) the SQL error is displayed with this line ```SELECT myschema.test_func_2('foo', 'bar') INTO l_table_result;``` is run. The functions create fine it's the execution I have problems with.

Comment: Since ```SECURITY DEFINER``` is specified, calling the function via super user should not make a difference, thus it is expected you get the error in both settings (or none). Eventhough creation is possible (perhaps just the way you choose via ```ALTER FUNCTION``` and not via ```CREATE FUNCTION``` with user ```myrole```) and you can call the function, inside the function you are acting as user ```myrole``` and the lookup for function ```myschema.test_func_2``` is executed by him, thus ```myrole``` needs at least the ```USAGE``` privilege on the schema. Have you tried granting it?

Comment: The GRANT USAGE has sorted it. I was thinking it was a function level issue but it was a schema level. Many thanks.